# Why is there overlap with two interfaces?

Tags: routing, router, subnet, ip-address

I am trying to configure router0, I assigned ip 192.168.26.1 to gigabitEthernet 0/0 and I tried to assign this ip: 192.168.26.33 to interface serial 0/0/0 but this error appears:

192.168.26.0 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/0

Serial0/0/0: incorrect IP address assignment

```
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 0/0
Router(config-if)#ip add
Router(config-if)#ip address 192.168.26.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-if)#no sh
Router(config-if)#no shutdown 

Router(config-if)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet0/0, changed state to up

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/0, changed state to up

Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#inter
Router(config)#interface ser
Router(config)#interface serial 0/0/0
Router(config-if)#ip add
Router(config-if)#ip address 192.168.26.33 255.255.255.0
% 192.168.26.0 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#no sh
Router(config-if)#no shutdown 
% 192.168.26.0 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/0
Serial0/0/0: incorrect IP address assignment
```

this is my subnet information:
[image]

this is my topology:
[image]

Comment: Those two addresses are in the same network based on the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two router interfaces in the same subnet.

192.168.26.1/24 (255.255.255.0) and 192.168.26.33/24 are part of the same subnet.   According to your diagram, you want to use a /27 mask, or 255.255.255.224.